# listing and grouping build id of multiple branches

Tags: azure, azure-devops, pipeline

**SCENARIO**:
let's consider I have a devops project.
I've got  3 branches namely test-1, test-2 test-3.
I've one build ipeline named "mybuildpipeline-CI"
from all the three branches I'm working I've made several commits and it leads to builds.

Consider there are 10 builds from test-1, 5 builds from test-2 and 7 builds from test-3 respectively. All the builds have a separate unique build ID number.

**QUESTION**:
1. how do I list the builds from each branch separately based on build ID number and based on branch name?
2. I want commands/ shell script to group the respective builds with their branches based on build ID number and based on branch name.